# EmguCV - Convert color image to rg chromaticity

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

Does EmguCV provide any built-in function for converting a color image into RG Chromaticity ([see Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rg_chromaticity))   ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any built-in method in EmguCV at least on v3.1 . So , I ended up doing the old way.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img_live = Live_Mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Live_Mat.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Live_Mat.Width; j++)
                {
                    float blue = img_live.Data[i, j, 0];
                    float green = img_live.Data[i, j, 1];
                    float red = img_live.Data[i, j, 2];

                    double sum = red + blue + green;
                    double r = red / sum;
                    double g = green / sum;
                    double b = blue / sum;

                    if (sum == 0)
                    {
                        r = 0;
                        g = 0;
                        b = 0;
                    }


                    img_live.Data[i, j, 0] = System.Convert.ToByte(Math.Round((b * AWB_rgb_mult), 0));
                    img_live.Data[i, j, 1] = System.Convert.ToByte(Math.Round((g * AWB_rgb_mult), 0));
                    img_live.Data[i, j, 2] = System.Convert.ToByte(Math.Round((r * AWB_rgb_mult), 0));


            }
```